# Docker Compose Up fails with; Skipping project "ProjectName" because it was not found. But the dockerfile works with visual studio docker compose

Tags: docker, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, directory

I have set up docker compose with visual studio and it works, spinning up containers and everything. But when I attempt to use

```
docker compose up
```

When it comes to the following in the dockerfile

```
RUN dotnet restore "DockerTestApi/DockerTestApi.csproj"
```

it fails, with several similar to the following

```
Skipping project "/src/ExternalDataProvider/ExternalDataProvider.csproj" because it was not found.
```

I guess it has to do with directories or something, but it is wierd it works through visual studio. One in my team uses vscode and needs to be able to start docker compose through that.

**Pictures:**

[terminal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMErN.png)

[Directory Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk2hv.png)

[Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O81t7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI When running from VS it does a bunch of [optimizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2022#debugging) that can by-pass the type of restore errors you're seeing.

Looking at your Dockerfile and errors, I suspect that changes have been made to the project structure since the Dockerfile was scaffolded.
Two recommended fixes:
You can regenerate the file by right-clicking on the project and selecting Add -> Docker Support...
-- OR --
You can delete lines 7 & 8 (the project specific COPY and restore). That's a build optimization that's nice but not needed.

Comment: Sry for the late response. I have attempted both your suggestions, and both seems to solve the problem of not finding the file and skipping it. I chose to go with the Docker Support, which changed the Dockerfile to copy all projects, otherwise it stayed the same. But now I get two projects that fail their restore, with errors such as:
`error NU1102: Unable to find package LogUtility with version (>= 6.5.3) [/src/DockerTestApi/DockerTestApi.csproj]`

Comment: Looking at NuGet.org I don't see that version for that package. I assume you have an internal package feed configured for your local build? If so, you'll need to provide a nuget.config in the container to configure that.

Comment: Sry, your right it is a private package.
Adding a NuGet.config file in the same folder as DockerTestApi.csproj with a reference to the private nuget server solved the problem, thanks :)

Just for curiosity, do you know why I need to copy each  project in the dockerfile when using docker compose up in vscode, but not when running docker compose in visual studio, for in visual studio it is simply enough with a reference to DockerTestApi.csproj?